# how to sort list of tuples in python with different size and element size

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

Can someone help me in sorting below tuple in Python?

```
({'b', 'c', 'a'}, {('b', 'c'), ('a', 'b')})
```

Expected output:

```
({'a', 'b', 'c'}, {('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c')})
```

Comment: In your example, you have a set of tuples. Do you want to sort `set` of tuples, or `list` of tuples? These are two different datatypes :)

Comment: Hi! Could you explain a bit more what you're trying to achieve, the inputs and their type, what you expect to have as outcome...?

Comment: ({'b', 'c', 'a'}, {('b', 'c'), ('a', 'b')}) is a python list of lists and i want output to besorted alphabetically like ({'a', 'b', 'c'}, {('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c')})

Comment: What you have provided in your example is not a list of tuples but rather a tuple of sets. e.g. ('b', 'c', 'a') is a tuple. {'b', 'c', 'a'} is a set. [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set) [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tuple#tuple) A list of tuples would look like:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your title and example are conflicting. You should consult the python documentation on [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set), [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tuple#tuple), and [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tuple#list)

Some Examples:

```
a_list = ['b', 'c', 'a']
a_tuple = ('b', 'c', 'a')
a_set = {'b', 'c', 'a'}
a_list_of_tuples = [('b', 'c', 'a'), ('b', 'c'), ('a', 'b')]
a_list_of_tuples_and_lists = [('b', 'c', 'a'), [('b', 'c'), ('a', 'b')]]
```

This example works for both a list of lists/tuples and a tuple of sets/tuples, however it returns an actual list of tuples **not** a tuple of sets as provided in your expected output example.

```
my_list = [('b', 'c', 'a'), [('b', 'c'), ('a', 'b')]]
print(tuple((sorted(item) for item in my_list)))
-> (['a', 'b', 'c'], [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c')])

my_tuple = ({'b', 'c', 'a'}, {('b', 'c'), ('a', 'b')})
print(tuple((sorted(item) for item in my_tuple)))
-> (['a', 'b', 'c'], [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c')])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're talking about a list of lists and that you want to first sort each list and then the whole list of lists.

You can do it as follows:

```
arr = [['b','c','a'],['b','c'],['a','b']]

for i in arr:
    i.sort()

arr.sort(key=lambda x:x[0])

print(arr) 

[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c']]
```

Remember the solution will be totally different if you have a tuple of sets or vice versa.

Comment: The solution looks helpful could you please help me if it is tuple of sets ?

Comment: It's not possible to sort sets in its original form, you need to covert it in a list and then perform sorting and if again you will try to convert it in a set, the order will change because a set doesn't maintain the order of elements. I hope this helps.